# to search for a number in the first column and change the value in second column depending on its value in linux

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have an input like below

```
$Interpreted from averaged nodal data
14725   0.0000000e+00
14726   0.0000000e+00
14727   0.0000000e+00
16263   6.4771147e-03
16264   6.3834046e-03
16265   6.4125084e-03
16266   6.5514743e-03
```

in between comes also sometimes text but when a line has a number it remains like shown above

I have to search for a certain number in the first position and then check the second number. If the second number is greater than a certain value like 0.002, it can remain like this, but if it is small than 0.002, the value changes to 0.002 in the same file. Like if I want to search 14725 and its value is zero file should turn to

```
$Interpreted from averaged nodal data
14725   0.0020000e+00
14726   0.0000000e+00
14727   0.0000000e+00
16263   6.4771147e-03
16264   6.3834046e-03
16265   6.4125084e-03
16266   6.5514743e-03
```

All the data is space seperated and before the number on left, we too have spaces. The left side always remains integer while right side will be always real.
Any suggestion with awk or sed -i for infile change?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk -v needle=14725 '$1 == needle && $2 < 0.002 { $2 = 0.002 } 1' filename
```

With `-v needle=14725` `needle` in the awk code will have the value `14725` (with a fixed value you could put this directly into the code, but I assume that this comes from a variable), and then

```
$1 == needle && $2 < 0.002 {   # if the first field is the searched number
                               # and the second smaller than 0.002
  $2 = 0.002                   # set the second field to 0.002.
                               # Use $2 = "0.0020000e+00" if the
                               # number format is important.
}
1                              # print.
```

With GNU awk 4.1.0 or later, you can use

```
awk -i inplace -v needle=14725 '$1 == needle && $2 < 0.002 { $2 = 0.002 } 1' filename
```

to edit the file in place.

**Addendum (answer to comment):** To keep the formatting intact, I would use

```
awk -v needle=14727 '$1 == needle && NF == 2 && $2 < 0.002 { sub(/[^[:space:]]*$/, "0.0020000e+00"); } 1' filename
```

The major change is that instead of `$2 = 0.002`, which causes the line to be rebuilt from fields, we use `sub(/[^[:space:]]*$/, "0.0020000e+00");`, which replaces the last batch of non-space characters in the line with `"0.0020000e+00"`. And, just to avoid screwups, we check that there are only two lines in the field.

Comment: it replace the numbers but unfortunately the format is lost, my data is actually space seperated and not tab seperated. It has to remain like this in order to parse the whole file for the next step. Can we keep the format same?

Comment: I added something for that. A bit hackish, but it should do.

Comment: thanks for the explanation that will help for learning the functionality!